# How can I force the Console to stay minimized in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to developing with Java and trying to get familiar with Eclipse (Luna) and when I test my web application the Console tab pops up over my code even when it's minimized. Is there a way to disable this? I cannot seem to find a setting for it and it's really annoying as i want to be able to look at and read my code while playing with this new app I'm working on. Gotta tab over and minimize it each time I do something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Would maybe be better asked on stackoverflow)

There's two checkboxes in Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console:
"Show when program writes to ...". If you disable that, the console will be less annoying.

Comment: Ah-ha! Perfect. Thank you. The joys of learning a new IDE :(